# ssh with password not working unless PermitRootLogin yes

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu 16.04 I have in my sshd_config

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

However non root users are always disconnected when trying to login.

Only when I set

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

non-root users can log in.

How can I allow non-root users to log in, but disallow passwords for root user?

Comment: Changing `PermitRootLogin` shouldn't do anything to non-root users.  Can you post the output of `ssh -vv` when connecting from your client as an unprivileged user?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem now. Will rebuilt copy of server from script and try to reproduce

Comment: Normally, ssh permissions are granted with `AllowUsers user1 user2` in sshd_config

Comment: @Broco the purpose of this setup is to provide SFTP access to different users of a shared web server. Can you elaborate on "normally"?

Comment: That should be `without-password`, rather than `prohibit-password`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton They are aliases.